# How can I load resources from another app?

Tags: android, resources

I'm developing an Android app for which we will be selling separate content in the Android Market.  Since Android lacks an in-app purchasing model as iOS has, I have come to understand that this is the ideal way of selling additional content (but NOT functionality) for Android apps.

So the question is, how do I actually load raw resources from other Android apps, assuming that I know the exact name of the resource, app ID, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are the standard way for apps to make their content available to others.